# Problem in datagridviewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my datagridview , when in click on datagridviewComboBoxColumn to populate its dropdownlist it not show me dropdown list for that i need to click 2 times. at first time it just focus to datagridviewComboBoxColumn and on second click it populate its dropdown. but i want to populate its dropdownlist on single click. please help me out. i am using c#.net (vs 2005)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual solution for this behaviour of the DataGridView is to set the EditMode property of the DataGridView to EditOnEnter.

There are some issues around using this approach, in particular that the row header is no longer available for row select. See [Microsoft Connect here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98504/datagridview-row-select-with-editmode-editonenter) for more info on that issue.